# MySQL table (re)design

Tags: mysql

We have "user" and "study" entities in our application, stored in their respective tables.
A study represents a kind of research and the data that has been gathered.
They have a many-to-many relationship, so we need a linking table: studies_users.

We assign roles to users. There are a few "normal" roles, which are study-dependent, so for the same user they can be different, depending on the chosen study. This means that those kind of roles would have to be stored as part of the studies_users table.

There is however a request for a new, "special" role, lets call it superadmin, which basically means the user has all possible roles (or rights) in all kinds of studies. That means such property wouldn't have to be stored in the studies_users linking table, it's sufficient to store it in the users table in a new column (is_superadmin for example), since it applies to all of the studies.

However, if I store it separately from other roles (in the users table), it seems to be somewhat illogical and can lead to unwanted complexity in the code that handles related logic.

Should I store such attribute in the linking table or in the users table? **Why?**

some very basic SQL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EMAIL` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `studies` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(150),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `studies_users` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STUDY_ID` int(10),
  `USER_ID` int(10),
  `ROLE_ID` tinyint(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

Comment: fair question, edited the post

Comment: Can you post the `create table` sql?

Comment: It would help if you provide some sample data. I don't know yet what kind of information roles and studies are.

Comment: And what is the problem to implement it as other roles - too many rows in `studies_users`?

Answer (score 2):

If you stick your DB design to the real world, 'superadmin' is an attribute of the user, functionally determined by the user only, and as such should be in table user. Yes, this will add some complexity to the queries but will spare you headaches when users change from superadmin to 'normal'; you will just need to change a flag and your data will remain consistent at all times.

Comment: I concur. A boolean "flag" on the user table would be the most efficient. A separate table with user_id as a (unique) foreign key is also workable, but that's an extra join in the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since your "superadmin" role is a special role, not like the other roles you describe, you shouldn't feel compelled to store them together in the same table. You may call them both roles but that doesn't mean they're the same thing.

The most straightforward approach would be to have a table storing the primary keys of all users who belong to this superadmin role. Adding a field to the user table means storing additional data (or even worse, `NULL`s) in every row, even when only a very small minority of your users are superadmins.